# Why does River Song save the Doctor in Let's Kill Hitler?

Tags: doctor-who

Could any one tell me why River Song saves the Doctor after kissing him with the poisoned lipstick? She was programmed to kill him, so why did she save him ?

Answer (score 9):

This is because of the following things:

1. She was trained to kill him, and the process involved getting to know everything about him. She got so involved in the knowledge about him that although she was trained and raised to kill him, she had started to have feelings for him.
2. She had been alone all her life, and yet, there was The Doctor, who was dying because of her poison, and yet was fighting to save her and her parents. This brought her back to her own senses as she didn't see any reason that The Doctor had to be killed.
3. She was trained to kill him but was never told the complete story as to *why*. So when The Doctor whispers whatever it is that he whispered, she decides to save him.